# How to run GitLab build stages in parallel?

Tags: gitlab, cypress

I've been running my end to end script for 3+ hours and i want to shortened it by running it on parallel. I've researched a ton of hours but i can't do it properly cypress cloud is supporting parallelization but this is not my option since it's paid service

I also tried this npm [cypress-gitlab-parallel-runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-gitlab-parallel-runner) but no luck it runs in series

I also tried it to do manually with different job in the same stage but it runs sequentially
Heres the snippet:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  image: cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107
  script:
    - npm ci && npm install

test1:
  image: cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run test-run1

test2:
  image: cypress/browsers:node18.12.0-chrome107
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run test-run2
```

How can I run an e2e script on parallel?